# HAVING clause without grouping by all non-aggregate columns in SELECT

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

HAVING clause without grouping by all non-aggregate columns in `SELECT`
I am often faced with tables that have an id column and a month column along with many other metrics. I weed out certain rows based on other columns. I only want to id’s that have all 12 months’ worth of data, so I do the following:

```
proc sql;
   create table t as
   SELECT *
   FROM  T1
   GROUP BY id
   HAVING COUNT(id) = 12
quit;
```

It seems to work for me, but I was wondering if there are any dangers with this method. I know I can join an aggregated subquery with only id and the count of ids, but this method is much easier to explain to non sql users.

In general, can you used the `HAVING` clause with only a couple of the columns in the `GROUP BY` and  no aggregate functions in the `SELECT` statement?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the database.  On one of mine (redbrick) the query your presented will throw an error.  To make it work, I'd have to change

```
select *
```

to

```
select id.
```

However, you might have misguided motivation.  I am usually interested in the most efficient way to get the correct answer.  Clarity to myself and anyone else who might have to maintain it is also important, but clarity to laypeople is not one of my priorities.

Comment: PROC SQL (SAS) does not throw an error when you select all columns and group by one of them.

Comment: I'm not surprised.  The s in sql means Structured, not Standard.  Plus, I didn't think you would post a query that crashes.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys.  In the example above it wouldn't matter what order I looked at the rows within each group, since I just want a count.  In this particular case, using the having in such a way wouldn't do any harm...right?  More generally, if I wanted to average or sum over rows of a particular id it shouldn't matter either...correct?                                                                                                                        I would get in trouble if I started trying to select the max or min something.  At least that is how I under stand it.

Answer (score 1):

When a GROUP BY clause is used, the selected values *must*<sup>1</sup> be derived from one of the columns selected for the group or the result of an aggregate function. This is because there is no guarantees in the Relational Algebra model as to which record will be selected -  some SQL dialects, such as SQL Server, will reject such construct with an error!

Now, say we wanted *all records* responsible for making this condition hold (i.e. "select non-grouped/aggregate columns"), we could use a join. A join is a simple way to handle this that showcases RA, but different databases may support the same result with different constructs.

```
select t.* from (
  select id
  from T1
  group by id
  having count(id) = x) as g
left join T1 as t
on t.id = g.id
```

However, this is *different* from the following (which is invalid in SQL Server):

```
select * -- ONLY the id column value is "well-defined" !!
from T1
group by id
having count(id) = x
```

Because in this latter case, there is only *one record selected per group*. This is also why it only makes sense to use columns that define the group or are aggregated from that group.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is not always enforced (depends on implementation) or required (depends on specific case), but I like predictable results all the time.

Answer (score 1):

SAS will permit you to do that, certainly, in its implementation of SQL (your tags suggest you are using SAS's implementation).  You will get a note in the log:

`NOTE: The query requires remerging summary statistics back with the original data`.

SAS actually performs the same query as in `pst`'s answer:

```
select t.* from (
  select id
  from T1
  group by id
  having count(id) = x) as g
left join T1 as t
on t.id = g.id
```

behind the scenes.  There's no technical reason why not to do it, unless you have a requirement at your jobsite to have clean logs (in which case you won't).  It's not terribly risky, but at the same time, why not explicitly write the join in?

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.* from (
  select id
  from T1
  group by id
  having count(id) = x) as g
left join T1 as t
on t.id = g.id
```